# Как добавить эффект на переход на другой view ?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Как сделать чтоб новый view при переходе делал как на видео в ссылке???
https://yadi.sk/i/lZ8sGCYNYSrcS

Comment: https://github.com/soleares/SOLPresentingFun   вот это еще крутая демонстрация возможностей анимации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте animated transitioning, вот тут есть объяснение как оно работает и как его использовать:

http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html

Answer (score 2):

Погуглите `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.
Вот хорошие статьи объясняющие как это использовать:

[objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html)

[doubleencore.com](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/)

[whoisryannystrom.com](http://whoisryannystrom.com/2013/10/01/View-Controller-Transition-Orientation/)